# Julia: how to remove rows by condition with a search across the entire dataframe

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Sometimes there is a need to delete rows by some condition in a large dataframe, where it is irrational to manually specify all columns by name. For example, such a situation may occur if the value "no data" is set as some specific numeric value, for example "-1". It would be useful to be able to immediately delete all the rows where this value occurs, similar to how `dropmissing()` removes them. I have not found a convenient way to replace an arbitrary value with "missing" or directly delete all lines where the specified value occurs.

Simple example:

```
df = DataFrame(A=[2, -1, 3, 3], B=[2, 5, 7, -1], C=3)
```

I want to delete all rows where -1 values occur, or at least extract all rows where this value does not occur. Something like this:

```
df_clear = df[df .>= 0, :]
```

or:

```
df_clear = df[findall(x -> x>0, df), :]
```

A similar syntax works with replacing values, but it doesn't seem to be applicable for deleting strings:

```
df .= ifelse.(df.< 0, 0, df)
```

What is the most elegant way to solve this problem? Is there a beautiful solution to perform such a check on a range of columns or on all columns except for the specified one?

Comment: Another options: `df[reduce(.&, df[!,x].>=0 for x in names(df)),:]` and `names(df)` can be replaced by a group of columns if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it e.g. like this (using the `ifelse` function you used; the approach assumes you do not have `missing` values in your data frame):

```
julia> dropmissing!(ifelse.(df .== -1, missing, df))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     2      2      3
   2 │     3      7      3
```

A more direct approach is to use the `subset` function by keeping rows in which `-1` is not present:

```
julia> subset(df, All() .=> ByRow(!=(-1)))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     2      2      3
   2 │     3      7      3
```

finally you could do the following using the indexing syntax:

```
julia> df[all.(!=(-1), eachrow(df)), :]
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     2      2      3
   2 │     3      7      3
```